# Remove null value in javascript for $.ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
var pageData = {
query: null,
pageNumber: 0,
pageSize: 30};
```

When I make an ajax get:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Ajax/GetSuggestions',
    data: pageData,
    success: function (response) {}
```

The request show in firebug: `http://localhost:31198/Ajax/GetSuggestions?query=null&pageNumber=1&pageSize=30`

At server side (ASP .NET MVC3), I received query = null in string, not null data(what I need).
How can I fix it without using delete method of javascript to remove null value?

Comment: What technology are you using on server side (e.g. PHP? ASP.NET MVC?)?

Comment: why don't you want to use `delete` to remove the null value?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to send data "over the wire". The standard one for sending form data to the server is url encoding. A second way is to send a JSON object. (A transmission detail is that the JSON would be url-encoded. But that's only a transmission detail.) A third way is to use XML.

As @jfriend00 shows in his answer, there are multiple, hacky ways to send a "null" value via url encoding. You should use the one which your server side stack best supports.

**Re: why the string "null"** What's happening is that the Javascript *value* null needs to be converted to a value that can be sent via HTTP ("over the wire"). The default way to do that is to use the string **null**. The problem is that the url encoding scheme only sends things as strings. So it doesn't have an automatic way to send the value null vs teh string null. The usual work around is an empty string, "".

But this can also raise an issue on your server-side since the string "" is not equal to the value *null* in most computer languages. So you will need to make appropriate comparisons or conversions. Eg does "" == *false* in your server software?

**Using JSON for the data encoding is the other technique.**

JSON directly supports a null value. It is is supposed to transmit it as `null`. See [JSON spec](http://json.org/) (not so obvious, search the page for null) and [IBM docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r1mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wbit.612.help.config.doc/topics/rjsonnullunsempprops.html)

The way you receive null data in JSON is the bareword `null`. If you're using JSON, note that you do not receive the string null, you receive the JSON keyword null. Your JSON receiver/decoder should know the difference. If it doesn't, then it is faulty.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong - he's **not** using JSON!  The parameters are being URL encoded, not JSON encoded.

Comment: Oops, I read the q very quickly. I've now updated to better cover the options and underlying issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your URL to look like this:

```
http://localhost:31198/Ajax/GetSuggestions?query=&pageNumber=1&pageSize=30
```

Then, you have to set query property to `""` (an empty string).

---

If you want your URL to look like this:

```
http://localhost:31198/Ajax/GetSuggestions?&pageNumber=1&pageSize=30
```

Then, you have to remove to remove the `query` property from the pageData object by either not putting it there in the first place or by using `delete pageData.query` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

When the request string is being built in jQuery, it's using every property on the `data` object it can find.

All you need to do to remove a property is `delete` the property:

```
delete pageData.query;
```